# How to get Associated Simple Product Id using Attribute Option Id of a Configurable Product Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

How to get Associated Simple Product Id using Attribute Option Id of a Configurable Product in Product View Page in Magento2?
For Ex: A Configurable Product with Attribute Size and Options L,M,S.  How to get Simple Product Id of L,M,S ?